# Constructor arguments from EVM bytecode

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, evm, security, bytecode

I have a contract that results to the following bytecode: **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**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SharingIsCaring {
    string public flag;

    constructor(string memory _key) {
        flag = _key;
    }
}
```

How can I read the public variable flag from the bytecode?

Comment: The variable `flag` is a string, so it is more complicate to work with. You could use remix to compile an obtain an assembly output that is easier to read. Why do you want to read the flag bytecode?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor arguments to are usually ABI encoded and appended to the end of the deployment bytecode. Since this is a string, the argument would probably look something like

[your_bytecode][0x20 padded to 32 bytes][length of string padded to 32 bytes][your actual string]

So for example if you wanted to set the `_key` value to "hello world" you would append:

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b68656c6c6f20776f726c64000000000000000000000000000000000000000000